# Toggle menu in two different direction

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want that my toggle menu slide left content from right to left and right content from left to right. I tired and I had done but toggle start from wrong place ( right side of menu button).  However when we click menu button one more time left and right content slide out correctly.

here link to my codepen: http://codepen.io/EmilBuszylo/pen/bgQZQp

```js
// Burger animation
$('.burger-menu').on('click', function() {
  if ($(this).hasClass("burger-menu-clicked")) {
    $(this).removeClass("burger-menu-clicked");
    $(this).addClass("burger-menu-closing");
  } else {
    $(this).addClass("burger-menu-clicked");
    $(this).removeClass("burger-menu-closing");
  }
});

// toggle menu
$('.burger-menu').click(function(){
  $('.nav-l').toggle('slide',{direction: 'right'} ,900);
  $('.nav-r').toggle('slide',{direction: 'left'} ,900);
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: #4A96AD;
   width: 100%; 
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

// hamburger button

[class^="line-"] {
  display: block;
  height: 7px;
  width: 50px;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 1px;
}

.burger-menu {
  display: inline-block;
  background: rgba(white, .15);
  border: 1px solid rgba(black, .15);
  padding: 9px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  transition: background .3s;
  text-align: center;
  &:hover {
    background: rgba(white, .2);
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  & .label {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 0;
    margin: 16px 0;
    letter-spacing: 0.15rem;
  }
}

.burger-menu-clicked {
  .line-1 {
    animation: menu-top .4s forwards ease-in-out;
  }
  .line-3 {
    animation: menu-bottom .4s forwards ease-in-out;
  }
  .label {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

.burger-menu-closing {
  .line-1 {
    animation: menu-top-reverse .5s forwards ease-in-out;
  }
  .line-3 {
    animation: menu-bottom-reverse .5s forwards ease-in-out;
  }
  .label {
    transition: .5s;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes menu-top {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg) translateY(0px);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(0deg) translateY(20px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(20px) rotate(45deg);
  }
}

@keyframes menu-top-reverse {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(20px) rotate(45deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(0deg) translateY(20px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0px) rotate(0deg);
  }
}

@keyframes menu-bottom {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg) translateY(0px);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(0deg) translateY(-19px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(-19px) rotate(-45deg);
  }
}

@keyframes menu-bottom-reverse {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(-19px) rotate(-45deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(0deg) translateY(-19px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0px) rotate(0deg);
  }
}

// Menu
.top {
  height: 100%;
  margin:  0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: rgba(255, 233, 243, 0.4);
}
.over-menu {
  .nav-l {
     display:none;
  }
  .nav-r {
     display:none;
  }
  li {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 35px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }
}
.show {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="top">
  <nav>
    <ul class="over-menu">
        <li>
      <ul class="nav-l">
        <li>category1</li>
        <li>category2</li>
      </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
      <div class="burger-menu">
      <span class="line-1"></span>
      <span class="label">menu</span>
      <span class="line-3"></span>
      </div>
        </li>
        <li>
      <ul class="nav-r">
        <li>category3</li>
        <li>category4</li>
      </ul>
        </li>
    </ul> 
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't see the problem.

Comment: when you click menu icon all content toggle from right said of menu icon but when click to toggle down right content hide on right side of icon and left content hide on left side of icon.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that jquery influences the layout by setting display: none on your hidden elements. I recommend to either fix your layout (preferably with flex-box) or just using a library like animate.css for small animations like these. You could then control yourself how to save the state (closed/open) instead of using display: none.

Comment: thx for advice, when I used toggleClass with slide css animation menu worked that I wanted but finally changed conception